# shell script How to open and read a particular line in a file and pass value to json

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have a html file. So now I wanted to open the html report and read particular line and also the result and save that value to a json file through a jenkins job.  have shell script to read whole file line by line. But how can i read a particular line which has a word `APPLE` in it and save it to a json file.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="data.html"
while read -r line
do
    name="$line"
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < "$filename"
```

This will echo whole page. But i need to search for a particular line having word APPLE.

Please help

Comment: You can write a script which can be executed on Jenkins.

Comment: yea that i know. what type of script. How to open a file and read a line and save to json. Can you help on that @Christopher

Comment: Which OS is running your Jenkins? What software is available on your Jenkins? E.g. you can use bash, python, ... Depends on your system.

Comment: Do you want to get only the lines that are containing the word `APPLE`?